# Is infrared blocking film effective in reducing temperature inside a room?

Tags: air-conditioning, cooling

I was going to put a foil on windows, but found a film that is alleged to reflect rays from infrared spectrum, thus preventing 60% of sun heat of entering a room.
Any criticism on it?
Or personal experience? Will it really help?

Comment: 3M has a film that will do what you ask and it only tints the window a little

Answer (score 1):

My house has no central air and lots of huge windows on the south, so it gets a bit toasty in the summertime.

I installed window film (brand is "Vista Window Film" if it matters).  I don't know what it does in terms of which part of the spectrum it blocks (IR or not?).

It has done a fantastic job.  It colors the view just a bit, though you only really notice when comparing against a non-tinted window.  Temperatures are bearable in the summer now.

Comment: Also, installing double pane windows specifically with e-glass will do the job quite well. If you walk past the windows in the morning, you will feel a beam of reflected heat due to them repelling infrared radiation transmission. You probably will notice a similar effect on windows with IR blocking film. Replacing all the windows with eastern exposure reduced morning room heating quite noticably which made for less heat in the afternoon.